# Add a button on GitHub pull request page to manually trigger Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

When developers upload their PRs for code review, our Jenkins detects this and runs all possible tests on them. Unfortunately we are out of resources, so those tests can take up to two days to complete.
Many times the developers are not interested in running all tests, only sanity. What I would like is to add a button on Pull Request page saying "Run Heavy Workloads" that will run heavy workloads, but the user must click this button, it is not enough he only uploads a new patch set. Is it possible to do this? How? If not, what are my other options?

Comment: Pull Request pages are generated by GitHub, you can't change them.

Answer (score 0):

We are achieving this in Gitlab by using tags. Jenkins run build for only those branches which have specific tags. I assume they are controlling this through code.

The below link might help to understand a little bit about it.

https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin